# toggle switch to enable and disable my listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, windows-phone

I am new to developing for window phone and I am trying to use a toggle switch to enable and disable a list box. Below is my code.... I am trying to use a toggle switch to enable and disable my listbox but I cannot get to work. Please, what am I doing wrong here?

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mylistBox.Items.Add("");
    mylistBox.Items.Add("5 seconds");
    mylistBox.Items.Add("10 seconds");
    mylistBox.Items.Add("15 seconds");
    mylistBox.Items.Add("20 seconds");
}

private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ListBox1.DisabledItemSelected += ("");            
}


private void ToggleSwitch_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Define "cannot get to work". Compile errors? Runtime exceptions? Spawns unicorns all over your screen? The phone melts? You've told us absolutely nothing about what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

This will switch the enabled status of your `ListBox` each time you fire this event.

```
private void ToggleSwitch_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Enabled = !ListBox1.Enabled;
}
```